# How to prevent entering date in the form

Tags: oracleforms

I want to allow to insert the date when the entered date is 'friday'. If the date entered is not 'friday', then the user should not be able to enter the data.

I am writing the following code, but event I give any date I am able to insert the date into the table.

```
DECLARE
   d_date   DATE;
   x        VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   d_date := :dummy.v_date;

   IF TO_CHAR (d_date, 'DY') = 'FRI'
   THEN
      x := SHOW_ALERT ('SUCCESS');
      GO_BLOCK ('DB_MACHINE');
      SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY ('DB_MACHINE', insert_allowed, property_true);
      SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY ('DB_MACHINE', update_allowed, property_true);
   ELSE
      x := SHOW_ALERT ('FAIL');
      GO_BLOCK ('DB_MACHINE');
      SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY ('DB_MACHINE', insert_allowed, property_false);
      SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY ('DB_MACHINE', update_allowed, property_false);
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have non english client character set. Try

```
to_char(sysdate,'DY','nls_date_language=''american''');
```